# vb.net Formatting for high performance

Tags: vb.net

I have recently noticed on my performance assist tool I use on Visual Studio 2013 any time I make a complex string

as a sample string:

```
"SELECT * from calls where randid = '" & randid & "'"
```

it will instead recommend using string format

```
String.Format("SELECT * from calls where randid = '{0}'", randid)
```

same with using value initializers
instead of

```
        Dim cb As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        cb.Database = dbfile
        cb.Server = dbserver
        cb.UserID = dbuser
        cb.Password = dbpassw
```

use

```
Dim cb As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder() With {.Database = dbfile, .Server = dbserver, .UserID = dbuser, .Password = dbpassw}
```

Do these formats actually improve the performance of an application or is it recommending these for aesthetics?

Comment: Do you have a performance issue in your application? Has profiling told you it's in string formatting calls? Did you try implementing both approaches and measuring which is faster? If not, it doesn't seem like the difference matters.

Comment: Also, you should use neither - parameter interpolation is more secure.

Comment: If your not going to use Parameterized queries your whole Db is in jeopardy.

Comment: What _performance assist tool_ are you using? Just out of curiosity. May not be advisable.

Comment: I do use parameterized queries - that specific case was just an easy string format I could make up. Currently using Coderush / Devexpress - looking to change possibly to a better option in the near future

Comment: Does your performance-assistance tool come with documentation saying why it makes particular recommendations? Maybe the performance metric includes maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity (I am absolutely sure that mini-optimizations are devilish) I have tested the difference with this code using LinqPad:

```
Sub Main
    Dim  test = "999"
    Dim sw = new Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    for i = 0 to 100000
        Dim s = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD = '" + test + "'"
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    sw.Elapsed.Dump("Concat")

    sw = new Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    for i = 0 to 100000
        Dim  s = string.Format("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD = '{0}'", test)
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    sw.Elapsed.Dump("Format")
End Sub
```

with these results:

```
Concat 
00:00:00.0101903 

Format 
00:00:00.0365234
```

The output changes noticeably if we use an integer for the test variable because now the concatenation should use ToString()

```
Dim test = 999

Concat 
00:00:00.0198107 

Format 
00:00:00.0485193
```

So, for whatever reason your tool suggest to use the string.Format approach it is not to get better performance.

Answer (score 1):

In the first one compiler will generate `String.Concat` method call for your string concatenation:

```
return "test" + value + "test";
```

it translated into

```
IL_0000: ldstr "test"
IL_0005: ldarg.0
IL_0006: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_000b: ldstr "test"
IL_0010: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object, object, object)
IL_0015: ret
```

Both `String.Concat` and `String.Format` will cause boxing (I assumed `randid` is an `int`). You should call `ToString()` on it anyway to make it better.

The second one is a lay. Compiler will generate properties assignments anyway, so

```
Dim cb As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder() With {.Database = dbfile, .Server = dbserver, .UserID = dbuser, .Password = dbpassw}
```

is transformed into

```
Dim cb As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
cb.Database = dbfile
cb.Server = dbserver
cb.UserID = dbuser
cb.Password = dbpassw
```

by compiler.

Comment: in that specific case randid was a random string but I understand what you mean anyways - so much of this is going to look the same to the compiler in the long run anyway.